# Где есть обучение по языку JavaFX Дайте сыллочку)

Tags: java, javafx

Начал изучать... Точнее решил изучать JavaFx не где не могу найти чего толкового. Не поможете найти источник инфы?

Comment: По ссылке есть 2 книги

Comment: Комментарий может не в тему, но скажу одно - НЕ НАДО! НЕ БЕРЕГИ СВОИ МОЗГИ И НЕРВЫ! Я писал проект с использованием JavaFX... Это самое худшее, что я изучал за последнее время. Напиши для каких целей тебе нужно JavaFX и я попробую написать тебе альтернативное решение твоей проблемы.  P.S. Java обычно используется для "back-end". Для "Front-end" используются совсем другие языки программирования

Comment: Antonio112009, Нужно для 3д цели. Вообщем приложение в 3д

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX это не язык, это грубо говоря фреймворк внутри jdk, скччайте книгу Шилда, полное руководство java 8, там есть о JavaFX